# How to implement Material Design "Full-width text field"?

Tags: android, material-design

I want to implement the "Full-width text field" from Material Design as seen here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-full-width-text-field

[image]

How do I do that using the Material Design library?

Available libraries are at least these in recent versions:

- `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`
- `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1`
- `com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1`

I started with an `EditText` as sollows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/receivers"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:hint="Receivers"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/new_message_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/receivers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_new_message"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top" />
```

which looks like that

[image]

- Is there a way to get the padding (20sp) value from a library constant?
- How do I remove the line at the bottom of an EditText?
- Where do I get the horizontal separators from?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, wrong link. Edited the question. The "Full-width text field" has no line at the bottom of the input field. "if it is defined as a dimension resource, yes" This is what I am trying to find out. Is it?

Comment: "This is what I am trying to find out. Is it?" -- you would have to rummage through [this list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/R.dimen.html) and see if what you want is there. Off the cuff, it doesn't look like it. My apologies for my confusion regarding the line on the `EditText`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Values for the text field

```
<EditText
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@null"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
  android:minHeight="?listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:paddingTop="20dp"
  android:paddingBottom="20dp"
  android:paddingLeft="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
  android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight" />
```

- `android:background="@null"` will remove the underline with implied 4dp padding.
- `android:minHeight="?listPreferredItemHeight"` expands to 56dp. The view will always be at least 56dp tall. And bacause of `android:gravity="center_vertical|start"` the text will always be vertically centered.
- `android:paddingLeft="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"` and `android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"` both expand to 16dp on phones and 24dp on tablets.
- Vertical padding is always the same - <s>16dp</s> 20dp as specified in [Material Design > Components > Text Fields > Full-width text field](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-multi-line-text-field).

#### Values for the container

The container looks like a `LinearLayout` which has introduced divider support in API 14. Use these attributes on your LinearLayout:

```
android:divider="?listDivider"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

Instead of `?listDivider` which is an attribute provided by your theme you can use any custom drawable reference.

#### Additional notes

**1)** There are some inconsistencies between Material Design specs and the actual values defined in appcompat-v7 library.

`listPreferredItemHeight` should return 56dp but instead it returns 64dp. Similarly `listPreferredItemHeightLarge` (unused in this case) returns 80dp instead of 72dp. You can fix this by redefining the attributes in your theme:

```
<item name="android:listPreferredItemHeight">56dp</item>
```

**2)** Do *NOT* use a color resource directly as a divider. It has implicit height and width equal to -1. You'll need a custom shape drawable.

Comment: Is `listPreferredPaddingLeft` a typo? I have `listPreferredItemPaddingLeft` in `com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values/values.xml`

Comment: @SimonWarta Yes it is a typo. What you said is correct.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky Thanks for confirmation, fixed.

Comment: According to material design *Top and bottom padding for text: 20dp*. Thus I think the vertical padding must be changed from 16 to 20dp.

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing) the item heights are 48dp (small, 24dp icon, single line text), 56dp (medium, 40dp icon, single line text), and 72dp (large, 40dp icon, multi-line text, 16dp top and bottom padding). Some (visual) padding is implied in text below baseline and above capitals.

Comment: Looks like “Full-width text field” gets some explicit additional padding, which makes sense due to a small number of rows (https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7Q1FhU3h5OVY5VlU/components_textfields_full4.png from https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-full-width-text-field)

Comment: Seems you are correct, thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer.